# In Keycloak, how to logout (expire a session of) user1 automatically when user2 tries to login using IDP login page?

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I am using Keycloak (KC) as my identity broker with OIDC.

1) Browse client application and press login button

2) Behind the scenes login button will call KC auth end point which will display IDP login page

3) User1 bookmarks the login page and enters credentials and start using the client website

4) User1 closes browser without signing out

5) User2 comes immediately and clicks on bookmarked page which displays IDP login page

6) User2 enters credentials and gets following error:

[Error Message][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn83h.png

7)Once user press on "back to application", user1 screen get displayed (which exposes user1 information to user2)

How can I expire user1's session if it is active when user2 tries to login using IDP login page directly without any problem.

Comment: Can someone help??

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a custom authenticator and add it to your authentication flow in Keycloak. Implement the Authenticator interface of Keycloak.

First, you need to get the list of sessions of the current user as follows:

```
List<UserSessionModel> userSessions = session.sessions().getUserSessions(context.getRealm(), context.getUser());
```

`session` is a KeycloakSession.
The `context` can be accessed inside the method authenticate you are going to override next.
Here we can start implementing the behaviour you are looking for:

```
 private void logoutOldestSession(List<UserSessionModel> userSessions) {
        logger.info("Logging out oldest session");
        Optional<UserSessionModel> oldest = userSessions.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(UserSessionModel::getStarted)).findFirst();
        oldest.ifPresent(userSession -> AuthenticationManager.backchannelLogout(session, userSession, true));
    }
```

Don't forget to deploy the jar file containing this behavior under deployments of your Keycloak distribution.
Also, you have to reference your authenticator under /META-INF/services.

Comment: Thank you Hansi for prompt reply. Is there any example which I can use to implement this custom authenticator? Sorry I recently started working on KC.

Comment: You can find here an example of enhancement that limits number of sessions per realm or client. https://github.com/mfdewit/keycloak/tree/KEYCLOAK-849-configurable-session-limits/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/authenticators/sessionlimits

Comment: Here is the issue on Keycloak Jira. https://issues.redhat.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/KEYCLOAK-849

Comment: Once I write my own authenticator, do I need to call logoutOldestSession from overriden authenticate method? I believe I also need to check if user2 is trying to login from the same IP address (same computer) as user1 then only call logout.

Comment: does user1 and user2 have the same credentials or they are two different users? can you give me more information, I need to understand better the issue you are facing.

Comment: User1 and User2 are two different Identities. User1 is using a public computer carrying above steps 1 to 4. User1's session is still  active and User2 tries to login using IDP login page (supposed to go through client app login page but for some reason uses IDP login page). Steps 5 to 7 in the problem statement. When User2 logs in while having User1 active session, Keycloak should expire User1's session (behind the scenes) and allow User2 to login smoothly with out compromising UI experience.

Comment: ahh I see, so you have to change the code of the method logoutOldestSession to log out all sessions in Keycloak. I didn't implement this behavior before but it can be done.

Comment: Thank you Hasni Iheb. Do I need to call logoutOldestSession from overriden authenticate method? Please confirm.

Comment: Exactly, you have nothing else to do.